# Crystal Reports without Records (is it possible?)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I've been developing an application using asp.net, Visual Studio 2010 and Crystal Reports 13. I need to develop a cover for some documents in crystal reports and the question is, if is there any way to develop it without passing a collection or a dataset to my report? I mean, I designed my report in crystal reports 13 (in header and detail sections) and using some  ITextObject in my report to fill information. I want to fill it with my values (by my webform), is it possible ?

Should I develop everything in header section to show it on crystal ?

It's only one page (cover).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to my understanding you should put all those unbound controls in unbound sections like header or footer because the bindable sections in the middle are rendered only when there are items in the dataset and even multiple times depending on the resultset and report layout.